# BackgroundWorker and Clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, clipboard

I'm going crazy with a simple code in which I use a BackgroundWorker to automate the basic operations. Should I add a content to the clipboard.

After executing this code in the method of the BackgroundWorker:

```
Clipboard.SetText (splitpermutation [i]);
```

I get an error that explains the thread must be STA, but I do not understand how to do.
Here more code: (not all)

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

private void btnAvvia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    count = lstview.Items.Count;
    startY = Convert.ToInt32(txtY.Text);
    startX = Convert.ToInt32(txtX.Text);
    finalY = Convert.ToInt32(txtFinalPositionY.Text);
    finalX = Convert.ToInt32(txtFinalPositionX.Text);
    incremento = Convert.ToInt32(txtIncremento.Text);
    pausa = Convert.ToInt32(txtPausa.Text);

    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    [...]
}

private void WorkFunction(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    [...]

    if (worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        [...]
        Clipboard.SetText(splitpermutation[i]);
        [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could marshal this to the UI thread to make it work:

```
else
{
    [...]
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Clipboard.SetText(splitpermutation[i])));
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Where is Dispatcher? What is 'this'? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @codemann8 In WPF, every UI element has a Dispatcher - this was in code behind

Comment: I don't have any experience in WPF, I'm using a standard WinForms C# Project...Is there an equivalent solution there?

Comment: @codemann8 `Form.BeginInvoke` should do the same thing for you.

Answer (score 3):

The `BackgroundWorker` runs on the .NET thread pool. Thread pool threads run in the COM multi-threaded apartment. To use the clipboard, you must be running in a single-threaded apartment. You could create your own thread and set it to run in an STA, but it would probably be best to use `Control.Invoke` (or `BeginInvoke`) to get back onto a user-interface thread (which must be an STA thread).

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're getting is because you're trying to do something on the UI thread from outside the UI thread (a `BackgroundWorker`, as the name implies, does something in the background, and for that it needs to create a separate thread).

While the answer posted by Reed (that is, by using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`) is one way to do avoid this exception, I'm wondering WHY you are trying to send something to the clipboard from the main work method in the first place...

The `BackgroundWorker` exposes events like `ProgressChanged` (which you can call periodically from your work method) or `RunWorkerCompleted` (which will fire when the main work method finishes).

Using `Clipboard.SetText` in either of these events should not cause the exception you're seeing, and this seems to be the preferable way of doing things on the UI thread when working with the `BackgroundWorker`.